# warning: error writing standard output (Broken pipe)

Tags: python, bash, awk, subprocess

I get this error when I try to execute more than one different `shell` script commands using python.

```
GET_CLUSTER_IP = "kubectl describe service "+SERVICE_CLUSTER+" | grep IP: | awk '{print $2;}'"
child1 = subprocess.Popen(GET_CLUSTER_IP,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
CLUSTER_IP = child1.communicate()[0]
print(CLUSTER_IP)


GET_NODE_IP = "kubectl describe service "+SERVICE_NODEPORT+" | grep IP: | awk '{print $2;}'"
child2 = subprocess.Popen(GET_NODE_IP,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
NODEIP = child2.communicate[0]
print(NODEIP)
```

Error I am getting:

> TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '**getitem**'
>   awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) warning: error writing standard output (Broken pipe)

I can execute the commands one at a time, but not like one command is executed and then the next.

Anyone knows the reason for this? Is there a way to close one pipe and then start another? Not closing the first pipe is the reason to break the next pipe?

Comment: Typo: You're missing the parentheses here: `child2.communicate[0]`.

Comment: Oh yes thank you so much :)

Comment: This `| grep IP: | awk '{print $2;}'` can be change to this: `| awk ' /IP:/ {print $2}'`